# How to set the limit for a form's submit time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a little game: "guess a number"
Here is the code in jsFiddle: [Guess Number](https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/9x0nLy43/21/)
What I want is to set the limit for guess time, after 7 times incorrect try, game over.
I try to put a `while` inside the form's submission, but I don't know how to pause the loop by the next submission.
html:

```js
var resultat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
$('div').html("( answer is : " + resultat + " )");

$('form').on('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputVal = $('#number').val();
    var nbInput = Number(inputVal);
    
    if(nbInput !== resultat){
        if (nbInput < resultat) {
            $('h2').html(inputVal + ' is too small');
        }else{
            $('h2').html(inputVal + ' is too big'); 
        };
    }else{
     $('h2').html('Yes! ' + inputVal + ' is the right number');
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Let's Guesse Number</h1>
<form>
    <p>Enter the number between 1 and 100</p>
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div></div>
<h2></h2>
```

Comment: So add a counter `var counter = 0; ` and increment it on each submission `counter++`, and check to see if it is less than 7

Comment: I know, I tried it, but as I said, I don't know how to pause the loop by the next submission, the loop just repeat 7 times and then get out of the loop to find the answer is right or wrong

Comment: There should be no loop at all

Comment: please abstract the the issue and separate it from your specific use. title should be more like "limit a function call to N times"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
var limitCounter = 0;
var gussedRight = false;
var resultat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
$('div').html("( answer is : " + resultat + " )");

$('form').on('submit', function (e){
    if(limitCounter > 7) {
       if(!gussedRight)
           $('h2').html('You are out of gusses');
       return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    var inputVal = $('#number').val();
    var nbInput = Number(inputVal);

    if(nbInput !== resultat){
        if (nbInput < resultat) {
            $('h2').html(inputVal + ' is too small');
        }else{
            $('h2').html(inputVal + ' is too big'); 
        };
    }else{
        gussedRight = true;
     $('h2').html('Yes! ' + inputVal + ' is the right number');
    };
    limitCounter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Let's Guesse Number</h1>
<form>
    <p>Enter the number between 1 and 100</p>
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div></div>
<h2></h2>
```

Comment: it works, great. But there is one more thing, if I guess the correct answer at the last time, it still says "You are out of gusses", the last chance is not in the count

Comment: @JiangLan look now i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var resultat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var compteur = 1;
$('div').html("( answer is : " + resultat + " )");

$('form').on('submit', function (e){
 e.preventDefault();
    var inputVal = $('#number').val();
 var nbInput = Number(inputVal);
    var counter = $("#counter").val();
    
 if (counter > 7) {
      $('h2').html('Number of attempts is over!');
      return;
    }
    if(nbInput !== resultat){
        if (nbInput < resultat) {
            $('h2').html(inputVal + ' is too small');
        }else{
            $('h2').html(inputVal + ' is too big'); 
        };
 }else{
     $('h2').html('Yes! ' + inputVal + ' is the right number');
    };
    counter += 1;
    $("#counter").val(counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Let's Guesse Number</h1>
<form>
    <p>Enter the number between 1 and 100</p>
    <input id="number" name="number" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="hidden" id="counter" value="0">
</form>
```

Comment: This code doesn't work, it shows nothing when I submit the form

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment your `compteur` variable (I'm assuming that you have it for this purpose) and check it's value on every submission. Something like this:

```
var resultat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var compteur = 1;
$('div').html("( answer is : " + resultat + " )");

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (compteur < 8) {
    var inputVal = $('#number').val();
    var nbInput = Number(inputVal);

    compteur++;
    if (nbInput !== resultat) {
      if (nbInput < resultat) {
        $('h2').html(inputVal + ' is too small');
      } else {
        $('h2').html(inputVal + ' is too big');
      };
    } else {
      $('h2').html('Yes! ' + inputVal + ' is the right number');
    };
  } else
    $('h2').html('You reached the limit of 7 guesses.');
});
```

I've updated [your fiddle so you can see it](https://jsfiddle.net/9x0nLy43/24/).

Comment: almost great, the last message after 7 try just shows instabtly, and then gone, I want the message stay, so I will try it myself

Comment: Oops! It was a copy/paste mistake. The `e.preventDefault();` must be before the checking. See my updated answer.